# Why Notepad++ says my files were modified by another program when I change timezone in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, notepad++, time-zone

Why Notepad++ says my files were modified by another program when I change timezone in Windows 8?

Reproduction steps:

```
- Open file in notepad++
- Change timezone
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce on any version of Windows and the current version of Notepad++

Comment: I am using Notepad++ v6.5.2 (UNICODE).
Windows 8 6.3 (Build 9600)

Comment: As I indicated, using the current version of Notepad++ and tested it on every possible version of Windows I could.  I wasn't able to reproduce.

Comment: I just installed and tested with Notepad++ v6.5.3 (UNICODE), which is the latest version. The behavior is the same, I don't know why you are not able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file modified date is stored in an absolute way so that it will show the correct time no matter the time zone. So when you change your time zone, it changes the displayed modified date on the file to be correct.

Notepad++ looks for a change in the displayed modified date, and when it sees one it displays this message.